# Is it possible to limit max RAM consumption for a application

Tags: windows, ram, rpa

Is there any way to limit RAM consumption application wise?

**Exact Problem** - I have installed RPA Express software in my windows 8GB PC.
As per RPA site, the system requirement is 8GB (free space). So my PC passes the restriction by a margin.
But as expected, my system slows down and hangs when I open the app.
Is it possible to limit the RAM consumption of the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Cross-site question: https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Job Objects.  First you need to add the process to a job object, then set memory limits on the job.

Documentation can be found on MSDN: [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Although that technically works any allocation above the threshold of the job object will fail which almost certainly will crash the application.

Comment: @AloisKraus: If you're restricting the working set, it should limit the amount of physical RAM the app uses without limiting the virtual memory usage.  So the application will start swapping when it hits its limit, but physical RAM will remain available to other applications to keep them running smoothly.